# Running external programs from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, shell, unix

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

run a matlab command/script that starts a unix terminal and from within that terminal starts external software. Matlab itself should be decoupled from that shell immediately.

On a Unix system, I am currently trying to start an external program from within matlab. I know that I can basically use the matlab command prompt as a terminal by adding an *!* in front of every command. However then, the program's output is also displayed within on the matlab command prompt and the program is killed as soon as matlab is closed.

Comment: Try adding `&` at the end (Linux-style). For example, `! program &`

Answer (score 1):

To start an external terminal, call that terminal emulator using the matlab system command. If gnome-terminal is your terminal:

```
system('gnome-terminal');
```

To pass parameters to the terminal use -e

```
system('gnome-terminal -e echo hello World');
```

This terminal will close immediately after it's finished running. So too keep it open:

```
system('gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"echo Hello World; exec bash\""');
```

Hope this helps. I similar command should work for other terminal emulators beside gnome-terminal.